# Marker cluster additional information about position, markets, etc

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I use Google Maps Api v3 for map generation.

Map, of course, contains markers on it, and they some of them are grouped into clusters (depending of the zoom).

What I need it to get "content" of those clusters, with ID's of grouped markers, and to add simple overlay layer with additional informations.

Can you help me how can I get information of grouped markers?

Thank in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The most easiest way is to use [MakerClustererPlus](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclustererplus/docs/reference.html).
There is method getClusterClass().